# Tinymce wrongly rewriting HTML

Tags: tinymce

I have a custom button that insert some HTML in the editor

[image]

First block of code is the button action and the second one is how the HTML is inserted

Any idea why it is rewriting it that way and how to stop it?

Comment: You basically don't put a <p> inside a <pre></pre> and tinymce sorts the content "as well"

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean, I am not putting any <p> tag

Comment: try to do this:
`<p><pre class="code-php"></pre></p>`

Comment: I get exactly the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to fix it, in the init function:

> valid_children : 'pre[code]'

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE includes the ability to insert code samples into the editor via its Code Sample plugin:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/

If you want to try to do this yourself you need to do a few things like using the `protect` configuration option to tell TinyMCE to allow your PHP tags.  See this TinyMCE Fiddle for a basic example:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Qdgaab

Comment: I know but the plugin doesn't allow me to add a class to the code tag which it is mandatory for me. Also, I'm not adding php tags, < and > are inserted as their html representations.